# Is it possible to prompt or force a user to upgrade their JVM with a JNLP?

Tags: java, jnlp

I need to prompt users to upgrade from JVM 1.5 to 1.6 when they run my Web Start application. Is this possible using JNLP settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [developers guide](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#208):

> The tag `<j2se version="versionNum">`
>   specifies a platform version, where
>   versionNum is 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, or 1.5.
>
> You can request a specific product
>   version by including a vendor URL in
>   the href attribute. For Sun's JREs,
>   the URL is
>   http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
>   For example, the following J2SE tag
>   will request any Sun 1.3.1
>   implementation:
>
> `<j2se version="1.3.1*" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>`
>
> You can see all the versions of the
>   installed JREs in the Java tab of the
>   Java Control Panel.

I'm guessing you can use '1.6' as versionNum as well...